# TeamCity 10.0.4 update password in application.config file

Tags: git, teamcity

We use TeamCity as a build server and git for source control. When we build release packages I would like to update the `password` for `imapClientConfiguration` in TeamCity and not have to do it manually. Risking having production passwords in Git does not seem like a good idea but TeamCity is more restricted and having it as a password parameter there is OK.

My question now is how I can get the value from a Team City parameter and transform it into my application.config file? Transforming other values I use SlowCheetah.

My understanding is that you should add it as a parameter under `System Properties` and then somehow pick it up during build. At the moment we use Visual Studio runner.

[image]

**application.config**

```
<applicationConfiguration
  apiUrl="http://localhost:13297/">
<imapClientConfiguration
  userName="test"
  password=""
  host="MAILSERVER-TEST"
  port="993"
  useSsl="true" />
</applicationConfiguration>
```

**application.Release.config**

```
<applicationConfiguration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"
    apiUrl="http://localhost:90/"
    xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(apiUrl)">

     <imapClientConfiguration
    userName="production"
    password="REPLACE"
    host="mail.domain.com"
    port="993"
    useSsl="true"
    xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
</applicationConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up with the following solution:

Add passwords and other information you do not wan't in Git, for example license keys as configuration parameters.

[image]

Now add a new file to git, I added a file called `PasswordChange.ps1`.

Add a new build step before the actual build and select PowerShell as runner type. Run the script from a file and set Script file to match the path of your newly created file. Add script arguments like this `-imapPassword %imapPassword%`

[image]

In `application.Release.config` set the value for `password` to `__imap_password_placeholder__` or something similar.

Then update your script with the following information:

```
param([string]$imapPassword, [string]$wordLicenseKey, [string]$excelLicenseKey)

$incomingMailServicePath = "Solution\Project\application.Release.config"
echo "Trying to change imap password for $incomingMailServicePath"
(Get-Content $incomingMailServicePath) |
 Foreach { $_ -Replace "__imap_password_placeholder__", $imapPassword } |
   Set-Content $incomingMailServicePath;
echo "Imap password changed"
...
```

All done.